# How to check jquery function is called or not using Jasmine.js version 1.3.1 framework?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, backbone.js, jasmine, jasmine-jquery

I have view function in my backbone application:

```
 test: function() {                       
    $('body').scrollTop(0); 
    var url = {STRING}.replace("{SEARCH_SUB_STRING}", "{REPLACE_STRING}");              
 },
```

How to check using Jasmine.js whether this: **$('body').scrollTop(0);**  - scrollTop is called or not and **replace() is replaced with {REPLACE_STRING} or not**?

And also, How to check `.trigger() , event.preventDefault() , .focus()` using Jasmine.js

For normal view function call check using jasmine.js framework version 1.3.1, I will do as below:

```
spyOn(SpyObject, 'ViewFunctionName').andCallThrough();
spyOn(SpyObject, 'CalledFunctionName1');
spyOn(SpyObject, 'CalledFunctionName2');
SpyObject.ViewFunctionName();
expect(mainBody.CalledFunctionName1).toHaveBeenCalled();
expect(mainBody.CalledFunctionName2).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spying on JQuery Selectors in Jasmine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337481/spying-on-jquery-selectors-in-jasmine)

Answer (score 2):

Like this

```
    spyOn($.fn, "scrollTop");

    ...

    expect($.fn.scrollTop).toHaveBeenCalledWith(0);
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6198122/957731)