# Testing directive that uses bootstrap popover

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I have directive that uses bootstrap's popover. It becomes popover when variable is set:

```
if (newValue.show === true) {
     element.popover('show');
}
```

How can I make spy test with karma/jasmine tests?

I tried this:

```
    spyOn(element, 'popover');



    it('should call bootstrap method popover', function () {
    $scope.$apply(function() {
        $scope.value.show = true;
    });
    expect(element.popover).toHaveBeenCalled()
});
```

But I get error:

```
    Expected spy popover to have been called.
    Error: Expected spy popover to have been called.
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not convinced this is the best way to do this, but I was able to get it to work by storing the element on the scope and spying on it that way.

In your directive

```
scope.element = element;
if (newValue.show === true) {
 scope.element.popover('show');
}
```

In your spec

```
spyOn(scope.element, 'popover')

...

it('should call bootstrap method popover', function () {
  $scope.value.show = true;
  $scope.$digest();//Or use your $scope.$apply 

  expect(scope.element.popover).toHaveBeenCalledWith('show');
});
```

Hope that helps.

**UPDATE**

popover is a jQuery plugin attached to `$.fn` so we can spy on it. 
https://gist.github.com/danmillar/1930277#file-bootstrap-popover-js-L160

```
it('should call bootstrap method popover', function () {
  spyOn($.fn, 'popover');
  $scope.value.show = true;
  $scope.$digest();//Or use your $scope.$apply
  expect($.fn.popover).toHaveBeenCalledWith('hide');
});
```

This is a nice explanation of why you can't listen on element
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6198122/3403178

Comment: When I try to create a spy in this manner - `spyOn($.fn, 'popover')`, I get an error - **Chrome 51.0.2704 (Windows 7 0.0.0) ERROR                                                                                                  
  Uncaught TypeError: $(...).popover is not a function**. Should I inject any dependencies in beforeEach()?

Comment: Have you included the plugin? It's not part of the core jQuery lib.

Comment: thanks for getting back. Ya, popover() is part of bootstrap.js, so I had to include bootstrap.js in my karma.conf.js under browser dependencies. That solved it!

Comment: Glad to hear that fixed it!