# How to test bootstrap popover call in anonymous function

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, unit-testing, jasmine

I have this right at the start of my controller:

```
$(function() {
        $("[data-toggle='popover']").popover();
    });
```

I would like to test that .popover was called. And tried using what was in this question: [Testing directive that uses bootstrap popover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24272107/testing-directive-that-uses-bootstrap-popover)

So my test looks like:

```
it('sets up bootstrap popups',function(){
            spyOn($.fn, 'popover');
            expect($.fn.popover).toHaveBeenCalled;

        });
```

The test passes but if I remove that function altogether from my controller the test still passes. I think it has something to do with I should spy on the outer anonymous function and check $.fn calls popover inside but am unsure how to do this.

Any ideas? Thank you

**EDIT:**

I have now tried in the controller:

```
$scope.testme = $("[data-toggle='popover']");
$scope.testme.popover();
```

and in the test:

```
spyOn($scope.testme, 'popover');
expect($scope.testme.popover).toHaveBeenCalled;
```

and the test will pass regarless of if I actually call .popover().

Comment: Is this resolved?

Comment: I have skipped this test for now :)