# How to set spy on jQuery selector in jasmine?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, tdd, jasmine

I want to spy jquery callin my directive:

```
link: function postLink(scope, element) {
                $('.report-datepicker', element).datepicker();
}
```

I've tried this one

```
 var datepickerSelector = '.report-datepicker';

    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $compile) {
         jQuerySpy = spyOn(window, '$');
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        element = $compile(angular.element('<date-picker></date-picker>'))(scope);

    }));

    it('should be use correct selectors', function () {
        expect(jQuerySpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(datepickerSelector, element);
    });
```

Test is failed because spy was never invoked.

Do you know how to set spy on $ properly?

Comment: Maybe this is relevant for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337481/spying-on-jquery-selectors-in-jasmine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fairly easy

```
it('should be use correct selectors', function () {
  spyOn($.fn, "datepicker").andReturn("bar");
  var result = $('.report-datepicker', element).datepicker();
  expect(result).toEqual("bar");
});
```

you can also try creating your custom spy to make it more specific for your case, but this one should work

Comment: In this case I just invoke datepicker in test case, but I want to test that datepicker was called in directive link function

Comment: then you have to post your link function as well otherwise there is no way telling how to trigger it, although in that case it sounds like your link function should change to controller so then you can test the controller in seperation