# How to use spyOn to mock jQuery value for a selector in Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm writing some unit tests using AngularJS / Karma / Jasmine and couldn't get Jasmine's 'spyOn' method to work. After I use `spyOn`, I'm still getting `undefined` for that selector.

## The problem

The issue I'm running into, is **after I run**

```
spyOn($("#username"), "val").and.returnValue("test@test.com");
```

I try to get the value of username like this:

```
$("#username").val();
```

and it is `undefined`.

## Code I want to test

```
function isValidEmail() {
       var email = $("#username").val();
       var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
       return email.match(regex);
 }
```

## Unit Test

```
'use strict';

describe('test/spec/controllers/validation.js - No controller', function () {

describe('email validation', function () {
     it('should be true for valid emails', function() { 
         spyOn($("#username"), "val").and.returnValue("test@test.com");
         var result = isValidEmail();
         expect(result).toEqual(true);
     });
});

});
```

Anyone see anything I did wrong?

Comment: Looks related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337481/spying-on-jquery-selectors-in-jasmine.

Comment: This actually is not a complete duplicate of that other question because this question includes the code-under-test (CUT) i.e. the `isValidEmail` function, while that other question does not. This is important because a more correct and elegant solution actually does not work for this CUT whereas that's not relevant to the other question. See my comments beneath the accepted answer for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that each time you call `$("#username")`, you get a different object. Therefore, the `$("#username")` in the function will not be spied on.

You should instead spy on `$.fn`, which will be shared by all jQuery objects.

```
spyOn($.fn, 'val').and.returnValue('test@test.com')
```

Comment: Looks like the same answer as in the potential duplicate... :P

Comment: The problem here is that the spy works when `val()` is called on _any_ jQuery object. So if you e.g. later change the username id in the html but not in the jQuery call then the test may still pass when it shouldn't. A more correct/elegant solution is the one in [a different answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5401235/5218951) to that other duplicate question. However that would require refactoring `isValidEmail` so that `email` is a function parameter, i.e. using dependency injection. That would be good, tho, b/c DI generally makes code more robust, flexible and, yes, testable.

Comment: To summarize a better solution: Refactor: `function isValidEmail($elmt) {var email = $elmt.val(); ...}`. Call in regular code: `isValidEmail($("#username"));`. Test: `it("should work", function() {var $elmt = $("#username"); spyOn($elmt, "val")...; var result = isValidEmail($elmt);...}`. Note: jQuery only called once, creating a single object. Even better, refactor: `function isValidEmailString(emailString) {...` and `function isValidEmail() {return isValidEmailString($("#username").val());`. Then testing `isValidEmailString` doesn't even need jQuery or even the DOM, just a test email string.