# SpyOn $ Jquery with Jasmine not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am trying to Mock a Jquery selector with Jasmine SpyOn

```
describe('initialising the navigation bar', ()=> {
it('should do something', () => {

  spyOn(window, '$').and.returnValue("bar");
  expect(utilityNavigation.test()).toBe('bar');

});
```

});

The code is as follows:

```
utilityNavigation = {
  test() {
    let foo = $('.utility-navigation');
    return foo;
  }
}
```

Simple stuff. When I debug the code in the Karma debugger and execute the `$('.utility-navigation')` in the console I get `bar` as expected from the spy. But the test result gives me a empty JQuery object not the return value from the spy.

Answer (score 2):

What you observe is absolutely correct. This should not work. `SpyOn` function has two parameters: 1. Existing object ("`window`" is existing object and there is no issues here); 2. String name of the function of this object ("`'$'`" is not the function of the window object.). I believe this is the answer on your question "why SpyOn $ Jquery with Jasmine not working?"

If you need more information on how to make it work, there are plenty of answers on SO regarding it; don't want to copy&paste the answers. This one, for example, would be great way to start: [Spying on JQuery Selectors in Jasmine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337481/spying-on-jquery-selectors-in-jasmine)

Answer (score 0):

- Use of window.$ should work just fine from a plain jasmine-javascript-jquery perspective
- I suspect the reason for empty div is may be the html element is not available on the page yet
- Can you try with an async callback `beforeEach` so that the div is loaded up just in case

Here is how I tried async div load up test using just `jQuery` and `jasmine` and it [works fine](https://jsfiddle.net/randomfifaguy/w1usxb7x/30/)

`<div class='utility-navigation' data-test="testString"></div>`

```
utilityNavigation = {
  test: function() {
    let foo = $('.utility-navigation');
    return foo;
  }
}

describe('initialising the navigation bar', () => {
  beforeEach(function(done) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log("waiting to ensure the div is loaded up on the page");
      done();
    }, 1);
  });
  it('should do something', () => {
    //pre    
    console.log(utilityNavigation.test().data('test'));
    var spy = spyOn(window, '$').and.returnValue("bar");
    //post
    console.log($('.utility-navigation'));
    expect(utilityNavigation.test()).toBe('bar');
  });
});
```